# Бот телеграмм и удалённые команды PYTHON

Tags: python, telegram-bot, localhost, python-telegram-bot

передо мной стоит следующая задача. Необходимо посылать команды удалённому ПК через бота в телеграмм, который подключён к этой же локальной сети. Я умею включать и выключать ПК, но не умею брать скриншот таким образом, передвигать курсор и т.д.. В связи с чем у меня два вопроса:

1. Как это сделать?
2. Будет ли являться костылём, если при запуске я поставлю в автозагрузку скрипт на другого бота телеграмм и один бот будет включать и выключать ПК, а другой управлять самим ПК? Таких ПК много и делать много ботов, как сами понимаете, не рационально. Поэтому склоняюсь к тому, что надо как-то сделать через хоста. Если что, всё делается через Windows, но на хоста могу поставить Linux, на удалённых ПК по-любому Windows 10 Pro, иначе нельзя.

P.S.: Если есть что-то подобное где-то почитать, скидываете, лишним не будет.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если LAN - необходимо использовать специальный PCI-модуль Wake on LAN. Иначе ни как его не включишь, если компьютер прям выключен (не в гибернации).
2. А что плохого в костылях? Но в любом случае, зачем такие сложности, если можно сделать одного бота, который будет по команде через тот же WOL отсылать команду включения/выключения (опять же, BIOS должен поддерживать, да и материнская плата), а после этого уже взаимодействовать.

P. S. Зачем телеграмм? Делаешь локальный сервер, ставишь на каждый компьютер WOL, и через консоль с правами root (можешь как угодно настроить), посылать команды, которые будут работать с компьютерами в локальной сети.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но смотрите в чём проблема. Не беда включать и выключать, так как это реализовано. Проблема в том, чтобы, например, брать screenshot с ПК, который включен, а бот стоит на ПК, который включен постоянно для функции WOL. Телеграмм даёт удобную реализацию задуманного, не хочется сейчас углубляться в интерфейс, главное сделать логику.
Ещё раз, проблема в том, что через WOL я не могу брать скриншот, управлять курсором и т.д..

Comment: @male23, неее, WOL только для включения. Просто без WOL и аналогов никак не включить. Я бы рекомендовал перейти на линукс, взять ту же убуняшу или дебиан, и залить им скрипты для удалённой работы. Не понимаю, зачем нужен телеграмм.

Comment: Т.е. Вы утверждаете, что с linux-хоста можно делать то, что я хочу? Удалённо посылать команды на Winodws ПК?

Comment: Я говорю что нужна локальная сеть, где каждый "рабочий компьютер" будет "знать", что он должен подчиняться валиндатным запросам (читай - сделать программу, которая на вход будет получать команду и ключ авторизации). А после забить на телеграмм (разве можно использовать для удалённого взаимодействия), и использовать "домашний сервер".